# How to change the icon dynamically?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4, font-awesome-5

I'm building an app using Ionic Angular, Font Awesome and Stripe. I want to change the icon on the HTML page based on the value I get from the server in the .ts page.

This is what I have:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let transaction of myRecentTransactions">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'cc-visa']"></fa-icon><span>{{ transaction.source.last4 }}</span>
</ion-item>
```

and this is what I want, but for some reason, it doesn't work:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let transaction of myRecentTransactions">
    <fa-icon [icon]="['fab', '{{ transaction.source.brand }}']"></fa-icon><span>{{ transaction.source.last4 }}</span>
</ion-item>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In property binding, use `transaction.source.brand` directly, no need of using interpolation.

Try like this:

```
 <fa-icon [icon]="['fab',  'cc-' + transaction.source.brand ]"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's worth mentioning that Stripe's card brand enums don't translate directly to font-awesome's and they may require a bit of tweaking (either on the server or frontend) before being passed to fa-icon: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=cc-, and https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-brand

Comment: Thanks. That worked, but as ttmarek said, I needed to add a cc- in front of the string to be like this:

<fa-icon [icon]="['fab',  'cc-'transaction.source.brand ]"></fa-icon>

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Yes. Try `'cc-' + transaction.source.brand`

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. Thanks for that.

Comment: Welcome. Please mark the answer as correct if it helped.